# js commands which used to work in node console not working when accessed from webpage

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I am unable to contact the local testrpc server that I set up when I am executing the javascript file through a webpage. Everything works fine when the js file is executed from the node console

My html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./malware.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

malware.js file

```
//create web3 object
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');
//alert("testing");

var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var code = fs.readFileSync('malware.sol').toString();

//deploy a smart contract instance from a node using code information generated during compilation
var malwareContract = web3.eth.contract(contract.info.abiDefinition);
var deployedContract = malwareContract.new({data: contract.code, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000});

//save the smart contract instance to access it later
var contractInstance = malwareContract.at(/*here the value obtained from contractInstance.address in the node console is used*/);

//here I am using an alert to check contractInstance.address
alert(contractInstance.address);
```

No part of the javascript code is running when it is accessed through the webpage.When I uncomment the first alert, nothing happens. However when I am running the same code in node console everything is printing as expected.

On further research, I found that require functions can't be directly called
from a webpage. What is the alternative for using web3 libraries

Answer (score 3):

you need to load the web3js in you webpage. the require function works only for nodejs not conventional javascript in a browser.

so first download form github [repo](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist).

add to your webpage the following ligne to load the web3js

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>
```

and in your malware file (what a name) add in the beginning the web3 object definition :

```
if(typeof window.web3 !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3.currentProvider !== "undefined") {
            var web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
          } else {
            var web3 = new Web3();
          }
```